# Extending rootfs on centos

Tags: lvm, lsblk

so I can see in lsblk that I have a 250G disk, but when I run pvresize /dev/sda3 I am not able to see the free space to extend the volume group.
Do I need to modify the partition table in single user mode since this is the root filesystem?
On a similar system, I was able to run pvresize, vgextend, lvresize and then resize2fs

[image]
[image]

Comment: `/dev/sda3` is only 10.3G in size so `pvresize` doesn't have any free room to expand into. You need to expand the partition first, then run `pvresize`. Also, [please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to expand the `sda3` partition first, as doneal24 said in the comments.

If your distribution has the `growpart` command (sometimes packaged as its own package, sometimes as `cloud-utils` or `cloud-utils-growpart`), it would offer an easy and safe way to extend the `sda3` partition: `growpart /dev/sda 3`.

As the `sda3` appears to be the "rightmost" partition on the disk, this command would most likely be able to extend the partition while the system is running, and have it take effect immediately, unless the kernel version is very old (and with very old kernels, it would take a reboot to make the partition table change effective).

If you have to do the partition table modification manually, remember two things:

- you can delete and recreate the partition entry, as long as the partition starting point will be exactly on the same block as before
- if the partitioning tool asks whether you want to clear any filesystem or LVM signatures from the partition, the answer is **no**.

If the partitioning change won't take effect immediately, you can try `partprobe /dev/sda` to make it take effect without rebooting. Eventually the partitioning tools will include all the things `partprobe` can do to update the kernel's idea of the partition table, but with some (older) versions of CentOS/RHEL, there is a chance `partprobe` knows some tricks the standard versions of partitioning tools won't have yet.

After that, `pvresize /dev/sda3`, then you can proceed to `lvresize`.

You don't need `vgextend` if you are expanding an existing LVM physical volume (PV): it's for extending an existing LVM volume group (VG) by adding other PVs to it. Since you have a separate `/boot` partition, there should be no problems in letting the LV containing the root filesystem extend to multiple PVs on different physical disks, if necessary.